# why can't my iphone app connect to my server?

Tags: iphone, rest, networking, get, afnetworking

i have a weird problem. so i've been working on an iphone app where a user can login, and upon logging in, the app would authorize the user by making an http GET request to the server. if the username and password is correct it return an authorization token (typical stuff).

the weird part is that when i test this locally, pointing the http request url to my local machine, it works fine. everything authorizes correctly and all data is returned correctly.

but today, i got the app stable enough that i decided to deploy rest api to my server, but when changed the http request url to my server url, the requests fails.

i thought maybe the server wasn't deployed correctly so i tested the http endpoints with the firefox rest client and everything seems to be working, authorization works, and data gets returned.

does anyone have any thoughts? i'm lost as to what the problem might be.

i'm using AFNetworking library to make the requests.

here's my code:

```
self.apiHttpClient = [[TKRHttpClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/api"]];

--------------

NSString *username = [usernameField text];
NSString *password = [passwordField text];
TKRHttpClient *httpClient = [TKRHttpClient sharedInstance];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/user/auth" parameters:nil];
[request addValue:username forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request addValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        NSDictionary * headers = [response allHeaderFields];
        NSString *token = [headers objectForKey:@"auth_token"];
        NSLog(@"token was %@", token);
        [[AppController sharedAppController] initializeDataForUserToken:token];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"upload failed!");
    }
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON ) {
    NSLog(@"code was: %i", response.statusCode);
    if(response.statusCode == 401){
        [errorMessage setText:@"Incorrect password or username"];
    }
}];
[operation start];
```

i put in break points, and it seems that the request goes straight to the failure block. the line that says "NSLog(@"code was: %i", response.statusCode);" in the failure block prints out 200. but when i tail the logs on my server, no request was received.

any help would be greatly appreciated. can't figure out for the life of my why it would work against my local tomcat, but won't work when deployed to my server.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Packet-sniff the connection, or run your phone through a proxy like Fiddler, and see what is going on.

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, you are sending the Username and Password without (https) encryption as GET params. This means anybody sniffing the connection will be able to steal your user's credentials

Comment: brilliant Brad! why didn't i think of that.. i did exactly as you said, but using charles instead. i found the issue. i'll post the answer. thanks again brad.  @TheRealKingK good eye. i'm just in the prototype phase right now. i'm planing to get the a ssl cert soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason for my problem thanks to @Brad's suggestion.

upon inspecting the request in charles, i found that the request was made as "http://mywebsite.com", then for path it was /user/auth. so the "/api" part was missing.

maybe this is the standard, i don't know, but it appears that AFHTTPClient's (my TKRHttpClient extends AFHTTPClient) initWithBaseURL really means the host URL. the "/api" part gets lopped off.

and the reason why it was working locally is because i deployed the app locally as root, so there was no "/api"

so two ways to fix this. 1. redeploy as app to server as root. or 2. change the line of code from:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/user/auth" parameters:nil];
```

TO:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"api/user/auth" parameters:nil];
```

hopefully this helps anyone using AFNetworking in the future.

Comment: This is documented in `AFHTTPClient`. If your `baseURL` includes a path, any absolute path parameters passed to the client will overwrite the initial path. So in your case, just replacing `@"/user/auth"` with `@"user/auth"` would do the trick.